# Compiler Optimization and UIView frame on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, optimization, llvm

I'm having a bizarre error where a custom subview of mine appears in entirely the wrong location on the screen under optimization but works flawlessly when optimization is turned off.

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
CGPoint newPoint = [self locationOfItem:i];
NSLog(@"setting new point to %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(newPoint));

CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(newPoint.x, newPoint.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
view.frame = newFrame;
NSLog(@"cell frame is %@ %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(newFrame));
```

Without optimization, this works flawlessly. Under any optimization flag except `-O0` (I'm using `-Os` but the problem occurs with any nonzero optimization level), I get:

```
2012-01-24 18:37:11.881 MyApp[36498:707] setting new point to {8, 92}
2012-01-24 18:37:11.884 MyApp[36498:707] cell frame is {{8, 8}, {68, 80}} {{8, 8}, {68, 80}}
```

which is, frankly, a terrifying response.

Note that the y-coordinate of `newPoint` is 92, but after being set into a rect and then passed to `UIView#setFrame`, it becomes 8, which completely breaks my display logic.

What's going on here? How could optimization cause this to happen?

I'm using LLVM 3.0, Xcode 4.2.1, compiling to armv6.

**Update**:

The below code seems to work fine:

```
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin = newPoint;
    frame.size = view.frame.size;
    view.frame = frame;
    NSLog(@"setting cell frame3 to %@ %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(frame));
```

Comment: I had similar issues in my project with LLVM + armv6 + CGFloats.  I ended up shipping armv7 only due to other issues.  However, prior to that, my workaround was leaving -O0 on for the armv6 portion.

Comment: Sorry for the storm of follow-up questions, but: If you ship with armv7, does your update just not appear for iPhone 3G users? Do you have to specify the devices you support when uploading to the App Store? I've always been afraid that if I ship with just armv7 my old users could end up downloading a "bricked" update. Also, is it possible to do a fat binary (armv6/armv7) and specify "-O0" for just armv6?

Comment: Question storms are good :)  From my understanding, you can't upload a binary which targets the same version of iOS as a previous binary, but removes hardware support.  You *can* increment the minimum iOS version required.  If you require iOS 4.3, only armv7 devices need to be supported, as only armv7 devices can run 4.3.  I shipped armv7-only from the start, so I haven't had real-world experience with this, sadly.  Let me try to dig up my old settings for your -O0 question.

Comment: I've appended a code snippet to my question that *does* seem to work, even though it should be equivalent.

Comment: @iccir, how did you disable optimization just for your armv6 binary?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, just read the end of your comment :)

Comment: In the build settings, you should be able to specify a setting for an architecture by using the (+) button.  See attached image for a better idea: http://imgur.com/SYExw

Comment: No problem!  Hopefully somebody can answer the original question and maybe get a patch into LLVM :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-mno-thumb` to your compiler flags.  This is a known issue with Xcode 4.2 targeting armv6 in Thumb mode.

Comment: Thanks so much. I had heard of this a few months ago, but I thought Thumb was off by default and this was only a problem if you actively chose to turn it off. Disabling thumb has fixed my weirdness. Really, really appreciated!